# HashiCorp Vault User Audit Capability

Tags: audit, vault

We're seeking a solution to enable us audit our HashiCorp Vault instance to obtain a namespace breakdown of:

- For each Vault user, the roles or groups that their entity belongs to.

Having reviewed the Vault API explorer commands, it appears this is not a capability that is available using that utility. There's been a suggestion that the HashiCorp Vault API client (HVAC) for Python might be a possible solution, but my initial research doesn't appear to indicate so either.

Will an API client like Postman for instance be the possible answer? Any recommendations or suggestions on how we can perform this task?